# TDD using namespacing (PHP) - Class not found

Tags: php, namespaces, tdd, classnotfound

I'm implementing some classes and I always end up with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Foo\Bar\Filter' not found in /blabla/filterTest.php on line 10
```

I have a test like this (filterTest.php):

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Tests\Bar\FilterTest;

use Foo\Bar\Filter;

class FilterTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testSth() {
        new Filter;
    }
}
```

And a Filter class like the following (filter.php):

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar;

class Filter {

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'foo';
    }
}
```

Any ideas? o.O

Comment: @OneTrickPony Do I need to include the file? I though with the namespaceing was not necessary... I don't have any autoload for the tests either.

Comment: Of course it is, PHP can't magically guess the file to include. And if namespaces were aliases of filenames, their declaration wouldn't be necessary, would it?

Comment: @OneTrickPony Ok, new thing to learn :) Anyway, still not working... I created an autoloader file so the file gets included. But when executing the test it first throws an error and then enters the autoloader function (I saw that with an echo in the loader function)... How should I deal with that? The autoloader file gets loaded using the phpunit's bootstrap option.

Comment: @OneTrickPony Oh, my bad >.< I didn't remember phpunit shows the echoes at the end... With including the file it's enought. Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was as easy as including the file where the class I needed was...

For those as like me didn't know that, you need to include the file. Namespacing won't do it for you ;)